# Can't lower values from array in PostgreSQL/Rails for case insensitive search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to refactor an array value search from jsonb column in Rails to make a case insensitive search.

I have the following code:

```
where('(offices.turn_filters -> :key)::jsonb ? :value OR offices.turn_filters -> :key IS NULL',
      key: key, value: value)
```

If understand this correctly, this query returns all offices where `:value` is present in the array or if the `value` is not present. Am I getting it right?

This is, this query would only return if it's an exact match, but I want it to be case insensitive.

I've tried doing something like:

```
where('(offices.turn_filters -> :key)::jsonb ? lower(:value) OR offices.turn_filters -> :key IS NULL',
      key: key, value: value)
```

But I think that I'm just lowering the param value and not the object value.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean "or if the `:key` is not present."?  Where should the case not be sensitive?  In the name of the `:key`, the value at `:key`, or both?  I don't think the keys can be matched case insensitively without expanding the keyset.

Comment: Hi @MikeOrganek! it should be insensitive in the value at `:key`.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally done with a lateral join.

```
with testing as (
  select * from 
    (values ('{"mykey": ["first", "SeCond", "third"]}'::jsonb), 
            ('{"otherkey": ["fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]}'::jsonb)) as x(turn_filters)
)
select t.*
  from testing t
  left join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(t.turn_filters->'mykey') as a(element_value)
    on true 
 where a.element_value ilike 'second'
    or not t.turn_filters ? 'mykey'
;

                turn_filters                
--------------------------------------------
 {"mykey": ["first", "SeCond", "third"]}
 {"otherkey": ["fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]}
(2 rows)
```

But it looks like ruby-on-rails has no support for `lateral join`.

This is uglier than hammered sin, but it works:

```
with testing as (
  select * from 
    (values ('{"mykey": ["first", "SeCond", "third"]}'::jsonb), 
            ('{"otherkey": ["fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]}'::jsonb)) as t(turn_filters)
)
select *
  from testing 
 where turn_filters->>'mykey' ilike concat('%"', 'second', '"%')
    or not turn_filters ? 'mykey'
;

                turn_filters                
--------------------------------------------
 {"mykey": ["first", "SeCond", "third"]}
 {"otherkey": ["fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]}
(2 rows)
```

Can you please see if this works for you?

```
where("offices.turn_filters ->> :key ilike concat('%"', :value, '"%') or not offices.turn_filters ? key",
      key: key, value: value)
```

Comment: ActiveRecord does not have a built in way to write lateral joins but you can still do them with string conditions or Arel.

Comment: Hi Mike! Thanks for taking your time to post this answer, finally we decided to go with: `where('(offices.turn_filters -> :key)::jsonb ? lower(:value) OR offices.turn_filters -> :key IS NULL',
      key: key, value: value)` and handle everything downcased! I did try your suggestion but I was getting a syntax error.